# How can we make edit Body input area larger?

Tags: 8

The Body field of the content on our website is generally quite large -- multiple pages.  When Editing in Drupal 8, the Input Area is quite small -- 98 characters wide by 9 lines.  The first thing we do is drag the bottom right of the Input Area and increase the size to 30-40 lines.  This makes editing much easier.

Is there a way to make the Body Input Area size 30 lines long for our website?  This would eliminate one step on every Edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go to the content types (or paragraph type) Form display settings and set the number of rows. No dev needed:

[image]

e.g. /admin/structure/types/manage/content_type/form-display

1. Click on the gear in the right column
2. Click update
3. Click save at the bottom

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting `#rows` for the textfield widget in `hook_form_alter()`.

This should work regardless of whether you are using CKEditor or a regular textarea form element.

For example (using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() which requires you to target the node edit form with FORM_ID),

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['body']['widget'][0]['value']['#rows'] = 30;
}
```